# Google app script, how can I change default Email font?

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail, font-size

I'm new to google apps script and stuck with changing the default Email font (size, color), Can anyone advise, please?

```
function sendEmail() {  
  xxxxxx
}
```

Besides any good tutorial guide for google app script besides, Google App Script developers site and youtube?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option would be to use html as your email body. You can use the function:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '', {htmlBody: **VARIABLE REPRESENTING HTML BODY HERE**})
```

As seen [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options), to send an email with html content, which would let you customize everything you could need.

**EDIT:**

As an example, here is a sample:

```
HTMLBODY = "<p>Hello, world.</p><br/><br/><b>This is</b> a demo email."
GmailApp.sendEmail('testabc@123.com', 'Demo Email', '', {htmlBody: HTMLBODY})
```

Comment: Your example doesn't use htmlBody.

Comment: @cooper htmlBody is the optional parameter name. The words `VARIABLE REPRESENTING HTML BODY HERE` would be replaced with the actual variable containing the HTML content.

Comment: This seems now to work for me:


function sendEmail() 
{

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
 var masterSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet ();
 
 var recipient = masterSheet.getRange (3, 20).getValue ();  
 var subject = "Global Report";
 var body='<p style = "font-family:roboto,light,300;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;"> Hi there, 
 xxxxxxxxx <br/>\nBest Regards, </p> ';
 
 
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject,"",{htmlBody: body}); 


  Logger.log(recipient);
}

Comment: Great, I'm glad! Would love it if you could accept my answer. Thanks!